# Is there a better method than mapping str to float then mapping to int?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge two data frames. In df_A the key is an int. In df_B the key is a string ending in .0 e.g. '10003.0'.

I would like to convert the string in df_B to an int for merging. Is there a better way than mapping twice as seen below?

```
df_B['key'].map(float).map(int)
```

The syntax seems awkward to me. Is there a better solution?

Comment: `def floatint(x): return int(float(x))` .. `.map(floatint)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```
pd.to_numeric(df_B['key'],downcast='integer')
```

Comment: It does work, but I actually timed slightly slower using that compared to `astype`

Comment: @user3483203 Yep, if speed do matter astype is the winner

Comment: This was my first downvote. I know downvotes should be explained. The reason was because I felt the answer was written in the spirit of racing to an answer, rather than writing a detailed and thorough answer. Maybe you could link to the docs, or explain what the function and its arguments do? Just my suggestion. I might be totally off base. Thank you for the solution anyway!

Comment: @JayCalamari Since here is not many logic behind it (why I did not explain too much), I can link the doc

Comment: @JayCalamari Just link the doc

Comment: @Wen, that sounds reasonable. The question did clearly ask how to convert a pandas series from string to float, and might not need a bunch of extra explanation.